# Left shifts and right shifts on boolean

Tags: c++, standards, c++14, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I am trying to understand exaclty how integral promotion works with arithmetic shifts operators. Particularly, I would like to know, which values of `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` are exactly defined according to the C++14 standard, and which ones can depend on the platform/hardware/compiler (assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`).

```
int a = true << 3;
int b = true >> 3;

int c = true << 3U;
int d = true >> 3U;

int e = true << 31;
int f = true >> 31;

int g = true << 31U;
int h = true >> 31U;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using bitwise operators for Boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542/using-bitwise-operators-for-booleans-in-c)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The question you linked does not talk about bitshifts at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [expr.shift]:

> The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

The result type of shifting a `bool` is always `int`, regardless of what's on the right hand side. We're never shifting by at least 32 or by a negative number, so we're ok there on all accounts.

For the left-shifts (E1 << E2):

> Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is representable
>   in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the
>   resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

1×2<sup>31</sup> is representable by `unsigned int`, and that's the largest left-shift we're doing, so we're ok there on all accounts too.

For the right-shifts (E1 >> E2):

> If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

E1 is never negative, so we're ok there too! No undefined or implementation-defined behavior anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Following is mainly a complement to Barry's answer, that clearly explains the rules for left and right shifting.

At least fo C++11, the integral promotion of a bool gives 0 for `false` and 1 for `true` : 4.5 Integral promotions [conv.prom] § 6

> A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

So in original examples, `b`, `d`, `f` and `h` will all get a 0 value, `a` and `c` both get a `8` value: only perfectly defined behaviour until here.

But `e` and `g` will receive the unsigned value `0x80000000`, so it would be fine if you affected it to an unsigned int variable, but you are using signed 32 bits integers. So you get an *integral conversion*: 4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral] §3

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

And unsigned 0x80000000 is not representable in a signed 64 bits integer so the result is **implementation defined** for `e` and `g`.