# How can I rewrite this assertion to make it pass once and fail later?

Tags: c++

As an exercise, I would like to check, in a single `assert`, if I have seen some (boolean) state before. Seeing it never is OK, seeing it once is OK, but seeing it twice should raise an assertion. (To be exact, seeing *anything* after seeing it once should raise an assertion.)

I have tried `assert(!(seen & (seen |= is_here)));` - however, this behaves very inconsistently across compilers.

- At https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/, it just works.
- At https://replit.com/languages/cpp, it works with helpful warning (`-Wunsequenced`)
- On MSVC, the third call fails already

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    bool seen = false;
    bool is_here;

    is_here = false;
    // these shall pass
    assert(!(seen & (seen |= is_here)));
    assert(!(seen & (seen |= is_here)));

    is_here = true;
    // this shall pass, but fails in MSVC
    assert(!(seen & (seen |= is_here)));
    // after that, this shall pass
    assert( (seen & (seen |= is_here)));

    is_here = false;
    // same as this
    assert( (seen & (seen |= is_here)));

    std::cout << "Done.";

    return 0;
}
```

I think I am hitting a wall of undefined behavior, so I have tried rewriting my expression, with no success. (I guess this may be more of a logical problem than a programming one.) I have tried rewriting using `&&` or `||`, which have sequence points, but since these are short-circuiting as well, I haven't found a correct expression yet.

Comment: Can you redesign it so that instead of `bool seen = false;` you have `int numberOfTimesSeen = 0;`? `assert(numberOfTimesSeen < 2)` seems much clearer and in line with what you want.

Comment: Worth reading the answer to [Using bitwise operators for Booleans in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24542/3422102) - you are fine, but ...

Comment: Perhaps a job for the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)?

Comment: `seen & (seen |= is_here)` is indeed UB.

Comment: `assert([&](){bool res = (seen & is_here); seen |= is_here; return res;}());`?

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, `int`s might work. I think one reason why they would work is because `int`s have a post-increment operator; if one could still use `bool++`, I would expect `assert(!(is_here ? seen++ : seen));` to work...

Comment: @jtbandes how would I use this? I think the comma operator would allow me to have a pre-increment of the saved state, but not a post-increment.

Comment: @Jarod42 `return !res` - otherwise, this looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error, I have been able to come up with `assert(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here))`, the point being that `?` introduces a sequence point separating the two evaluations of `seen`. In addition, `true | ...` sets the value of the latter branch without short-circuiting.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    bool seen = false;
    bool is_here;

    is_here = false;
    // pass
    assert(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here));
    assert(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here));

    is_here = true;
    // passes
    assert(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here));
    // after that, this passes
    assert(!(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here)));

    is_here = false;
    // same as this
    assert(!(seen ? false : true | (seen |= is_here)));

    std::cout << "Done.";

    return 0;
}
```